# Docker permission issue despite being in the group

Tags: docker, permissions, ubuntu-18.04

Hello (and happy new year!),
I'm having an issue since a while now : I run a project under Ubunutu (18.04) with docker but I must use every command on docker in sudo mode :

```
docker ps
```

I get :

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

```
sudo docker ps
```

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                             PORTS               NAMES
>   blablabla

Browsing for an answer, I found several posts solving this issue by adding the user to the group docker, which I did but with no result.

```
groups $USER
```

> gpdis : gpdis adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker

As the docs I found just stop with the "add the user to docker group and that's all, your problems should be gone", no way for me to try something else, someone has an idea?

Thanks a lot

EDIT :

Workaround I've found and use now, for those who could be concerned by this issue: As I use oh-my-zsh, it seems that there is an issue with permissions, I'm not registered in the docker group, no matter what command I do. I changed the permission of /var/run/docker.sock from 660 to 666, and it works now. Other possibility : to switch to su with a sudo su, this way oh-my-zsh isn't used and you have full control on docker.

Comment: Hi, can you show the output of `ls -al /var/run/docker.sock`?

Comment: Hi, here's the output : `srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 janv.  7 09:50 /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Did you do a re-login after your changes?

Comment: Yes, I did, I switched off the computer also, no change. :/

Comment: Hello, did you resolve this problem? I am facing the same problem. I am running the same image on two machines, both Ubuntu 18.04. Everything works fine without root but as member of the docker group on the one machine but not on the other one.

Comment: Hello, no news on my side, I continue to look for an answer some times and I still have to run every docker command with sudo.